# Hibernate Validator @ScriptAssert not called

Tags: hibernate, validation

i'm trying to perform a cross field validation using  @ScriptAssert . But it's never executed. I don't know why. My code it's similar to this:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.passVerify.equals(_this.pass)")
public class MyBean {
 @Size(min=6, max=50)
 private String pass;
 private String passVerify;
}
```

I've tried crazy things like the next code expecting to receive some kind of error, but noting happens:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "ANYTHING", script = "SARASA")
public class MyBean {
 @Size(min=6, max=50)
 private String pass;
 private String passVerify;
}
```

I've tried with HV 4.1.0 Final and now with hv 4.3.0 Final.
Thanks. am.

Comment: I have the same problem - have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you did the validation for this bean? If you are using Spring MVC, the validation code should be like:

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    value = "/a/b"
)
public String save(@Validated final MyBean myBean, final BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // do something
    }
    ...
}
```

I hope that'll be helpful.